# React state keeps resetting to initial state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, formik-material-ui, react-forwardref

I'm currently working on a mobile signature feature on my website. I have three components I'm dealing with: Form.js (parent, using Formik for the form), Admin.js (child of Form), and Signature.js (child of Admin).

When you arrive on this page (the Admin section of the Form) on portrait mode, it renders a message to turn your phone landscape to sign. When you turn landscape, a button pops up: 'Click here to sign'. When you click that, a full screen material-ui dialog pops up with a signature canvas (react-signature-canvas). You sign and then click 'Save and Close' to close the full screen dialog and then click 'Save Signature' to save the signature to your profile.

Using breakpoints, I've discovered that when you click 'Save and Close' in the dialog box to close it, the state is correctly being saved with the signature. But by time you click 'Save Signature' on the Admin section of the form, the state has been reset to it's initial state of null.

I believe the solution is to use the forwardRef hook but the problem is most of the examples I see are forwarding a ref from one component to another, and I think I need to have it pass through an additional component the way my components are structured (passed from Signature --> to Admin --> to Form). **I need to get the ref of the SignatureCanvas (react-signature-canvas) from Signature.js to Form.js.** Here's the relevant info for each file:

Signature.js

```
const Signature = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return (
        <SignatureCanvas
           backgroundColor="transparent"
           canvasProps={{
              width: mobileWidth,
              height: mobileHeight - 60,
              className: 'sigCanvas',
           }}
           penColor="black"
           ref={ref}
         />
     );
};
```

Admin.js

```
const Admin = () => {
    const { values } = useFormikContext();
    const signatureRef = useRef(null);

    return (
       <Signature values={values} ref={signatureRef} />
    );
 };
```

Form.js

```
const Form = () => {
    const { values } = useFormikContext();
    const signatureRef = useRef(null);

    return (
       <Admin ref={signatureRef} />
    );
 };
```

I researched and thought maybe I need to be using a useCallback hook instead of forwarding ref or using refs at all but wasn't sure how to implement if that is the correct solution. I've also tried setting the state in the Form component and passing it down to Admin and then to Signature but not having any luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will solve your issue, but you can pass `ref`s down several components by using `forwardRef` multiple times.

I created an example to showcase this which you can view on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/flamesdev/pen/oNWppNQ).

```
const DeeplyNestedComponent = forwardRef((_, ref) => <input ref={ref} />);

const NestedComponent = forwardRef((_, ref) => (
  <DeeplyNestedComponent ref={ref} />
));

const BaseComponent = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  const ref = useRef();

  return (
    <>
      <p>Last input value: "{inputValue}"</p>
      <NestedComponent ref={ref} />
      <button onClick={() => setInputValue(ref.current.value)}>
        Read input
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think of using forwardRef multiple times haha thank you.

Now the issue I'm running into is this: I actually have two SignatureCanvas elements in the Signature.js file, one that is rendered for desktop and one that is rendered for mobile, and they both have ref={ref} because I figured React will use whichever one is not null? The desktop rendered one works perfectly, but the mobile rendered one is still resetting state to initial state of null. Any idea? I tried giving different ref names but it didn't change anything

Comment: @JamesMaddox You're welcome. Are the `SignatureCanvas` components being rendered simultaneously (as in they are both in the DOM at the same time)? Also, what state is being reset? I don't see `useState` in your code.